# Use v-window component to create a stepper in Vuetify3 and Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I want to create a stepper component based on a  component and a  component in Vuetify3 and Vue3. The stepper component is currently unavailable in Vuetify3 (only in Vuetify2).
I implement the stepper that contains 5 steps. When we are at step 1, step 2 ~ step 5 is disabled. Step 3 ~ Step 5 is disabled when we are at step 2, and so forth. I want to use 'index' to recognize the specific  in the v-for loop, but it doesn't work. I also read v-slot is available with , for example, "isSelected". But I have no idea how to use them further, with a lack of documentation. Thank you.

My template

```
<template>
  <v-dialog scrollable activator="parent" width="1024px">
    <v-card theme="light" flat rounded="0">
      <v-item-group v-model="onboarding" class="text-center">
        <v-item
          v-for="(number, index) in length"
          :key="`btn-${number}`"
          v-slot="{ isSelected, toggle }"
          :value="number"          
        >
          <v-btn flat :variant="isSelected ? 'tonal' : 'text'" :class="{active: isSelected}" @click="toggle">
            <div class="text-h6 flex-grow-1 text-center">Schritt {{ number }}</div>
          </v-btn>
        </v-item>
      </v-item-group>
      <v-window v-model="onboarding">
        <v-window-item v-for="n in length" :key="`card-${n}`" :value="n">
          <v-card v-if="n === 1" class="d-flex justify-center align-center">
            <ApplicationModal1></ApplicationModal1>
          </v-card>
          <v-card
            v-if="n === 2"
            class="d-flex justify-center align-center"
          >
            <ApplicationModal2></ApplicationModal2>
          </v-card>
          <v-card v-if="n === 3" class="d-flex justify-center align-center">
            <ApplicationModal3></ApplicationModal3>
          </v-card>
          <v-card v-if="n === 4" class="d-flex justify-center align-center">
            <ApplicationModal4></ApplicationModal4>
          </v-card>
          <v-card v-if="n === 5" class="d-flex justify-center align-center">
            <ApplicationModal5></ApplicationModal5>
          </v-card>
        </v-window-item>
      </v-window>

      <v-card-actions class="justify-end">
        <!-- <v-btn variant="plain" @click="prev">zurück</v-btn> -->

        <v-btn variant="text" @click="next">weiter</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

My script

```
<script>
import ApplicationModal1 from './ApplicationModal1.vue'
import ApplicationModal2 from './ApplicationModal2.vue'
import ApplicationModal3 from './ApplicationModal3.vue'
import ApplicationModal4 from './ApplicationModal4.vue'
import ApplicationModal5 from './ApplicationModal5.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    ApplicationModal1,
    ApplicationModal2,
    ApplicationModal3,
    ApplicationModal4,
    ApplicationModal5
  },
  data: () => ({
    length: 5,
    onboarding: 0,
    activeStep: null,
    isLastStep: false
  }),

  methods: {
    next() {
      this.onboarding = this.onboarding + 1 > this.length ? 1 : this.onboarding + 1
    },
    prev() {
      this.onboarding = this.onboarding - 1 <= 0 ? this.length : this.onboarding - 1
    },
    activate(step) {
      this.activeStep = step
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is.  "it doesn't work" is quite a vague problem statement.  Is it the disabling that you're having trouble with?  If that is indeed the problem, you don't need to add `index` since `number` can already fill that role can't it? just add something to the button like `<v-btn :disabled="number > onboarding"`, then all items ahead of the item you're already on will be disabled.